# How to find smaller angle from startAngle and endAngle in html canvas arc?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, angle

I want to always have a smaller angle and I don't know how to decide counterclockwise ore not in drawing arc in html canvas.

This is my code

```
this.ctx.beginPath();

const startAngle = Math.atan2(P1.y - P2.y, P1.x - P2.x);
const endAngle = Math.atan2(P3.y - P2.y, P3.x - P2.x);

this.ctx.arc(P2.x, P2.y, 40, startAngle, endAngle, true);
```

[image: smaller angle]
[image: larger angle]

Comment: What values you get when the angle is the greater one? Do you get only `0 to 360` degress values?

Comment: I get startAngle = 3.1415, endAngle = 0.5743 in radians, not in degrees.

Comment: try this: `endAngle - startAngle >= Math.PI` as condition for your last argument last line

Comment: I already try it, not working in all cases

Comment: Could you attach a snippet?  With your `js` code and minimal `html, css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with vectors in the 2D plane.  Counterclockwise is determined by the right hand rule and the out-of-plane direction.

The [vector cross-product](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-cross-product.html) is the operation you need.  The angle is counter clockwise if the sign of the vector you obtain by crossing the first vector into the second is positive.

The cross product will give you a normalized vector that is either `(0, 0, 1)` for counterclockwise or `(0, 0, -1)` for clockwise.  Normalize the cross product and look at the sign of the z-component.

Comment: I did this counterclockwise = (P2.y - P1.y) * (P3.x - P2.x) - (P2.x - P1.x) * (P3.y - P2.y) < 0;

Comment: The cross product will give you a normalized vector that is either (0, 0, 1) for counterclockwise or (0, 0, -1) for clockwise.  Normalize the cross product and look at the sign of the z-component.